# Remove and update an array without mutation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array :

```
let originalArr = ['apple', 'plum', 'berry'];
```

How can I remove "plum" from this array without mutating the `originalArr`?

I can think of below approach :

```
let copyArr = [...originalArr];
originalArr = copyArr.filter(item => {
     return item !== 'plum';
});
```

Comment: `filter` creates a new array so the copyArr is not needed in your second snippet.

Comment: What do you mean by better way?

Comment: Not sure I get it. *Do we have any better way to remove item and update the originalArr variable*. But I thought you were asking how to remove it without mutating `originalArr`... What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have mentioned the last line..removed it now

Comment: What do you mean with "without mutating"? originalArr should maintain the 'plum' entry and create another array without it? Or you need to remove the plum without modifying the reference of the array. For the latter case use `splice`:    originalArray.splice(originalArray.indexOf('plum'), 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating *two* additional arrays: one `copyArr` and one filtered array. There's no need for both, creating just the filtered array should work fine, eg:

```
setOriginalArr(
  originalArr.filter(item => item !== 'plum')
);
```

as an example, if `originalArr` is in state.

Calling `.filter` on an array doesn't mutate the array it was called on - it returns a new, separate array, so it's safe to use in React without cloning the original array beforehand.

Comment: thanks..but this code is in an angular service and `originalArr` is a service variable. I guess i will need to reassign as well right? As in, `originalArr = originalArr.filter(item => item !== 'plum')` ?

Comment: You tagged the question with the reactjs tag, so I took you at your word. But even outside of React, the same thing would work. If you have to reassign the existing variable name, then yes, `originalArr = originalArr.filter(item => item !== 'plum')`

Comment: awesome..thanks. Just tagged to react as well so that I can get reviews from broader community :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice() method to extract items from/to specific indexes (without mutation of original array)

```js
let originalArr = ['apple', 'plum', 'berry'];
let sliced = originalArr.slice(1, 2)
console.log(originalArr, sliced)
```